# Invalid Leads from Meta Ads (Audience Targeting Issue)

Tags: advertising, social-media, facebook-ads-manager

I'm having an issue with audience targeting for my clients' lead form ads. I am receiving leads from 2-5 hours outside of that target radius I've set.

It should also be mentioned that my ad account is housing all of the client campaigns. I am running a lead campaign for each of my clients and they all have various service areas. I'm aware this is not best practice and am trying to rectify this by creating pages and ad accounts for each client at the moment, however I need an interim solution.

I've consulted Meta support and they mentioned that I am most likely getting the invalid leads because my campaigns are all in the same ad account and they all have the same objective but different target audiences. SO- My current idea is to add exclusion radiuses around each client ad set's target area. Therein sort of geofencing and hopefully tightening up the lead results. However, I'm worried that if I do add the exclusions, the same thing may happen with the campaigns but in reverse (Campaign A's inclusions might be affected by Campaign B's exclusions, and so on.)

Does anyone have any experience with this or ideas for a interim solution while I still have everyone on one ad account?